# Что нужно сделать, чтобы bad requests не выводились в консоль?

Tags: javascript

Делаю запрос на сервер await fetch, если, к примеру, данные не корректны, то в коносоль получаю данные запроса, как это убрать?

Comment: о каких данных речь?

Comment: смысл в том, что сервер просто не двухсотым отвечает и получаю bad request

Comment: `await fetch(...).catch(() => {})` или весь блок в try catch

Comment: А зачем вы это хотите?

Comment: Не хочу, чтобы в консоли были красные надписи и тем более url сервера

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, и так все в try catch, но ошибка все равно